# Initialize Bootstrap Scrollspy After Removing the Active Class

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap scrollspy working on load perfectly, however on a mouseover event using Angular, I have some of the navbar content change, and in doing so I remove the active class from the relevant list item. On mouseleave it reverts back, but the active class does not return. How do I properly reinitialize scrollspy so it comes right back, **without having to scroll again** to retoggle it? I tried the refresh method but it did not work.

My relevant code excerpts:

HTML:

```
<body style="padding-top: 0px;" data-spy="scroll" ng-app="SpringMill">
<section id="intro" class="main style1 dark">
<!-- Header -->         
            <header ng-controller="MainController" ng-mouseleave="isOver=false" id="header">

                <!-- Logo -->
                    <h1 id="logo">Summer Mill</h1>
                    <a ng-mouseover="isOver=true" style="color:black;text-decoration:initial;" id="logoii" href="http://localhost/locations">Locations</a>

                <!-- Nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li ng-repeat="headerLink in headerLinks">
                          <a ng-if="!isOver" ng-init="addActiveList()" href="#{{headerLink.text}}">{{headerLink.text}}</a>
                          <a ng-if="isOver" ng-init="removeActiveList()" href="#{{headerLink.alternativeText}}">{{headerLink.alternativeText}}</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </header>
```

Angular:

```
$scope.removeActiveList = function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active"); 
  },

  $scope.addActiveList = function() {
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#nav' })
  };
```

If not possible, should I maybe do something different like try to hide the active class and then bring it back depending on the state of `isOver` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I solved this by using jquery to create an intermediate class.

```
$scope.removeActiveList = function() {
        $(".active").addClass("tobeactive");
        $(".active").removeClass("active");         
      },

      $scope.addActiveList = function() {
        $(".tobeactive").addClass("active");
        $(".tobeactive").removeClass("tobeactive"); 
      };
```